# Error on validation on record create MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc, validation

I have compared my code extensively but can't figure out what's wrong.

**SITUATION**

I have a STUDENTS (Alumnos) table with two foreign keys, GROUP (Grupo) and TEACHER (Empleado)

I have a TEACHER (Empleado) table with three foreign keys, SCHOOL (Escuela), GROUP (Grupo) and ROLE (Puesto)

**PROBLEM**

When attempting to create a STUDENTS record with all but the GROUP and TEACHER (from the dropdowns) selected I get the following error:
The ViewData item that has the key 'EmpleadoID' is of type 'System.Int32' but must be of type 'IEnumerable'.

However when I attempt the same thing with a TEACHER record everything works fine and I get the corresponding validation messages next to the drop down, as it should be.

The code for these two cases is obviously not identical but basically the same structure.

Below both sets of code:

***FROM STUDENTS***

**CONTROLLER**

```
   public ActionResult Create()
    {

        var AluGru = from g in db.Grupoes
                     where g.ID != 1
                     select g;

        var AluEmp = from e in db.Empleadoes
                     where e.PuestoID != 1
                     select e;

        ViewBag.GrupoID = new SelectList(AluGru, "ID", "Grupo1");
        ViewBag.EmpleadoID = new SelectList(AluEmp, "ID", "FullName");

        return View();
    }

    // POST: Alumnoes/Create
    // To protect from overposting attacks, please enable the specific properties you want to bind to, for 
    // more details see http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=317598.
    [HttpPost]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public ActionResult Create([Bind(Include = "ID,Nombre,Apellido,Telefono,Estado,GrupoID,EmpleadoID")] Alumno alumno)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            db.Alumnoes.Add(alumno);
            db.SaveChanges();
            return RedirectToAction("../");
        }

        ViewBag.GrupoID = new SelectList(db.Grupoes, "ID", "Grupo1", alumno.GrupoID);
        ViewBag.EmlpeadoID = new SelectList(db.Empleadoes, "ID", "Nombre", alumno.EmpleadoID);

        return View(alumno);
    }
```

MODEL

```
public partial class Alumno
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    [Required(AllowEmptyStrings = false, ErrorMessage = "Nombre es requerido")]
    public string Nombre { get; set; }
    [Required(AllowEmptyStrings = false, ErrorMessage = "Apellido es requerido")]
    public string Apellido { get; set; }
    [Required(AllowEmptyStrings = false, ErrorMessage = "Telefono es requerido")]
    public string Telefono { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public string Estado { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public int GrupoID { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public int EmpleadoID { get; set; }


    public virtual Grupo Grupo { get; set; }
    public virtual Empleado Empleado { get; set; }
}
```

VIEW

```
@model _3E_III.Models.Alumno

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Create";
}

<h2>Create</h2>


@using (Html.BeginForm()) 
{
    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()

    <div class="form-horizontal">
    <h4>Alumno</h4>
    <hr />
    @Html.ValidationSummary(true, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
    <div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Nombre, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
        <div class="col-md-10">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Nombre, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Nombre, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Apellido, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
        <div class="col-md-10">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Apellido, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Apellido, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Telefono, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
        <div class="col-md-10">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Telefono, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Telefono, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
        </div>
    </div>

    <div id="hidestate" class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Estado, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
        <div class="col-md-10">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Estado, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control", @Value = "Inactivo" } })
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Estado, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.GrupoID, "Grupo", htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
        <div class="col-md-10">
            @Html.DropDownList("GrupoID", null, "Selecciona un grupo", htmlAttributes: new { @class = "form-control" })
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.GrupoID, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.EmpleadoID, "Maestro", htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
        <div class="col-md-10">
            @Html.DropDownList("EmpleadoID", null, "Selecciona un maestro", htmlAttributes: new { @class = "form-control" })
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.EmpleadoID, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
        </div>
    </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            <div class="col-md-offset-2 col-md-10">
                <input type="submit" value="Create" class="btn btn-default" />
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
}

<div>
    @Html.ActionLink("Back to List", "../")
</div>

@section Scripts {
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jqueryval")
}
```

FROM TEACHERS

CONTROLLER

```
    public ActionResult Create()
    {

        var GID = (from g in db.Grupoes
                   where g.ID != 1
                   select g);

        var PID = (from p in db.Puestoes
                   where p.ID != 1
                   select p);

        ViewBag.EscuelaID = new SelectList(db.Escuelas, "ID", "Nombre");
        ViewBag.GrupoID = new SelectList(GID, "ID", "Grupo1");
        ViewBag.PuestoID = new SelectList(PID, "ID", "Puesto1");
        return View();
    }

    // POST: Empleadoes/Create
    // To protect from overposting attacks, please enable the specific properties you want to bind to, for 
    // more details see http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=317598.
    [HttpPost]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public ActionResult Create([Bind(Include = "ID,Nombre,Apellido,EscuelaID,PuestoID,GrupoID")] Empleado empleado)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            db.Empleadoes.Add(empleado);
            db.SaveChanges();
            return RedirectToAction("../");
        }

        ViewBag.EscuelaID = new SelectList(db.Escuelas, "ID", "Nombre", empleado.EscuelaID);
        ViewBag.GrupoID = new SelectList(db.Grupoes, "ID", "Grupo1", empleado.GrupoID);
        ViewBag.PuestoID = new SelectList(db.Puestoes, "ID", "Puesto1", empleado.PuestoID);
        return View(empleado);
    }
```

MODEL

```
public partial class Empleado
{
    [System.Diagnostics.CodeAnalysis.SuppressMessage("Microsoft.Usage", "CA2214:DoNotCallOverridableMethodsInConstructors")]
    public Empleado()
    {
        this.Alumnoes = new HashSet<Alumno>();
    }

    public int ID { get; set; }
    [Required(AllowEmptyStrings = false, ErrorMessage = "Nombre es requerido")]
    public string Nombre { get; set; }
    [Required(AllowEmptyStrings = false, ErrorMessage = "Nombre es requerido")]
    public string Apellido { get; set; }

    public string FullName { get { return Nombre + " " + Apellido; } }

    public int EscuelaID { get; set; }
    public int PuestoID { get; set; }
    public int GrupoID { get; set; }

    public virtual Escuela Escuela { get; set; }
    public virtual Grupo Grupo { get; set; }
    public virtual Puesto Puesto { get; set; }
    [System.Diagnostics.CodeAnalysis.SuppressMessage("Microsoft.Usage", "CA2227:CollectionPropertiesShouldBeReadOnly")]
    public virtual ICollection<Alumno> Alumnoes { get; set; }
}
```

VIEW

```
@model _3E_III.Models.Empleado

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Create";
}

<h2>Create</h2>


@using (Html.BeginForm()) 
{
    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()

    <div class="form-horizontal">
        <h4>Empleado</h4>
        <hr />
        @Html.ValidationSummary(true, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Nombre, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Nombre, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Nombre, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Apellido, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Apellido, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Apellido, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.EscuelaID, "Escuela", htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.DropDownList("EscuelaID", null, "Selecciona una escuela", htmlAttributes: new { @class = "form-control" })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.EscuelaID, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.PuestoID, "Puesto", htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.DropDownList("PuestoID", null, "Selecciona un puesto", htmlAttributes: new { @class = "form-control" })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.PuestoID, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.GrupoID, "Grupo", htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.DropDownList("GrupoID", null, "Selecciona un grupo", htmlAttributes: new { @class = "form-control" })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.GrupoID, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            <div class="col-md-offset-2 col-md-10">
                <input type="submit" value="Create" class="btn btn-default" />
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
}

<div>
    @Html.ActionLink("Back to List", "../")
</div>

@section Scripts {
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jqueryval")
}
```

From what I can tell both should work fine, is there anything I'm missing?

Comment: Not sure if that matters for the main problem, but there is a bug. In GET version of Create method you assign:
ViewBag.EmpleadoID = new SelectList(AluEmp, "ID", **"FullName"**);
but after then in the POST version you assign text based on **Nombre** property, not on **FullName**:
ViewBag.EmlpeadoID = new SelectList(db.Empleadoes, "ID", **"Nombre"**, alumno.EmpleadoID);

Comment: I reverted from FullName to Nombre, got the same error, btw the error points to this line:

Line 61:                 @Html.DropDownList("EmpleadoID", null, "Selecciona un maestro", htmlAttributes: new { @class = "form-control" })

Given all fields populated it was saving fine to the database with FullName.